# A question regarding Graph embedding in plane

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, connectedness, planar-graphs

I am new to Algebraic Topology. So, I would like to have a detailed proof of this following problem as there are many similar and corollary problems in the book that I am reading.

Suppose we are given an embedding of a graph $G$ in the plane  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Here $G$ could be a multigraph, i.e. multiple edges between two vertices as well as loop edges on a single vertex are allowed. And suppose the number of vertices is $V$, the number of edges is $E$ and the number of connected components of $G$ is $C$.  I am required to show that the number of connected components of the complement $\mathbb{R}^{2}-G$ is $E - V + C + 1$.

The only result related to graphs that I have seen so far is the calculation of fundamental group using the Van Kampen theorem. But I am totally at loss regarding how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This result is called Euler's Formula for plane graphs, and you should be able to find a proof in most graph theory texts that discuss planarity. 

If you are comfortable with spanning trees and spanning forests, you can also start with a spanning forest of your graph (one tree per connected component) and do it by induction on the number of edges.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez Thanks for letting me know that. Can you please share the names of such texts that discuss planarity?

Comment: Bondy and Murty's *Graph Theory* (2008) has a proof for connected graphs (from this it's pretty easy to extend to more components). Diestel's *Graph Theory* has a proof that uses the strategy of starting with a tree and adding edges (Diestel is a pretty nice text for planarity). Alternatively, if your topology is a bit stronger, Mohar and Thomassen's *Topological Graph Theory* handles all these basic theorems (including Jordan Curve Theorem) in full rigor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: construct a clever choice of CW structure on $S^2$ so that your result follows from the fact that $\chi(S^2) = 2$ and that the Euler characteristic of a CW complex is given by the number of vertices less the number of 1-cells plus the number of 2-cells.

(A careful proof that this works uses the Jordan curve theorem, but you are surely expected to sweep this detail under the rug.)

Comment: I somewhat get the idea. Can you please make it a full fledged answer?